# How to convert using atoi and strtok with multidimesional arrays?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, integer, converters

```
Okay so i have this mltidim array filled with these numbers,
```

i wish to convert them into ints at the locations
So its gonna be a int multidim arrayint    intarray[2][5][12];
Any tip on getting the converter to solve the issue? ive been on this problem a while and it
feels like im close!!

char chararray[2][5][40] =
{

```
        {
                {"307,07,33,307,11,44,307,12,31,307,16,10"},
                {"308,07,52,308,11,52,308,12,35,308,16,18"},
                {"309,07,24,309,11,40,309,12,30,309,16,14"},
                {"310,07,15,310,11,38,310,12,36,310,16,27"},
                {"311,07,12,311,11,47,311,12,30,311,16,12"}
        },

        {
                {"314,07,12,314,11,34,314,12,27,314,16,52"},
                {"315,07,15,315,11,49,315,12,31,315,16,13"},
                {"316,07,59,316,11,44,316,12,38,316,16,42"},
                {"317,07,52,317,11,41,317,12,30,317,16,12"},
                {"318,08,03,318,11,32,318,12,39,318,16,07"}
        }
};
```

And this is how i am trying to convert but it doesnt even let me debug just a weird error pops up..

```
int intarray[2][5][12];
    for(int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 5;j++){
            for(int k = 0; k < 40;k++){
                intarray[i][j][k] = atoi(strtok(chararray[i][j][k],","));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: err, your bound value for k is 40, but the intarray size is only 12.

Comment: Yep because the char array is 40, so it will only add to the int array when the strtok hits the ","

Comment: The size of chararray does not matter in the second loop. It will try to write to intarray[i][j][39] despite values or the size of chararray and most likely fail with a memory error.

Answer (score 0):

`intarray[i][j][k]` for `i==0`, `j==0`, `k==0`, represents `3` which is the the character residing at `intarray[0][0][0]`.  This is a single `char` and cannot be processed using `strtok()`.

What you really want to pass to `strtok()` is a complete null terminated string:

```
char chararray[0][0]
```

which is the 40 character buffer containing `"307,07,33,307,11,44,307,12,31,307,16,10"`.
But because you probably do not want to destroy the array, you should start of by getting a duplicate of the string,  something like this:

```
int intarray[2][5][12] = {{0}};//zero before using
int i=0;
char *dup = strdup(chararray[0][0]);//in your actual code this will be in
                                    //a loop of `i,j` indexes, each one
                                    //yielding the character buffers: 

            //{"307,07,33,307,11,44,307,12,31,307,16,10"},
            //{"308,07,52,308,11,52,308,12,35,308,16,18"},
            //{"309,07,24,309,11,40,309,12,30,309,16,14"},
            //{"310,07,15,310,11,38,310,12,36,310,16,27"},
            //{"311,07,12,311,11,47,311,12,30,311,16,12"}

            //{"314,07,12,314,11,34,314,12,27,314,16,52"},
            //{"315,07,15,315,11,49,315,12,31,315,16,13"},
            //{"316,07,59,316,11,44,316,12,38,316,16,42"},
            //{"317,07,52,317,11,41,317,12,30,317,16,12"},
            //{"318,08,03,318,11,32,318,12,39,318,16,07"}



if(dup)
{
    tok = strtok(dup, ",\n");
    while(tok)
    {
         intarray[0][0][i] = atoi(tok);
         tok = strtok(NULL, ",\n");
         i++;
    }
    free(dup);//so you can use it again and again for the other sub-strings.
    ....
```

Following this approach, all of the other *strings* can be parsed into `intarray`

Answer (score 0):

Each `chararray[i][j]` is a *string* - `chararray[i][j][k]` is a single character in that string.  Unfortunately, you're passing the *single character* to `strtok` when it expects the address of the first element of the string.

When you're tokenizing repeated elements in a string, you only pass the base address *once*, then pass NULL for the remainder of the string.  So your loop would need to be

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 5;j++){
        intarray[i][j][0] = atoi( strtok( chararray[i][j], "," ) );
        for(int k = 1; k < 40;k++){
            intarray[i][j][k] = atoi( strtok( NULL, "," ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this assumes your input is always well-formed - there's no sort of error or sanity checking.